# add bootstrap menu instead of the default menu

Tags: joomla-4.x

I would like to make menu on mobile devices have the same behaviour as Bootstrap menu, right now the menu slides from right to left on mobile, i want to change this to toggle-open from top to bottom as the behaviour from boostrap menu and add some HTML/CSS Customisations to it.

Comment: To assist someone that might be able to help you can you add to your question what version of Joomla you are using, the name of the Template you are using and perhaps a link to your site if it is publicly accessible.